# Split a koalas column of lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

How do I go from df to df1 where df and df1 are shown below?

```
df = koalas.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF", "NYG"] for _ in range(7)],'teams1':[np.random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(7)]})
df
output:
    teams   teams1
0   [SF, NYG]   0
1   [SF, NYG]   5
2   [SF, NYG]   8
3   [SF, NYG]   1
4   [SF, NYG]   2
5   [SF, NYG]   8
6   [SF, NYG]   5
```

```
df1 = koalas.DataFrame({"col1": ["SF" for _ in range(7)],\
                        "col2": ["NYG" for _ in range(7)],\
                        'teams1':[np.random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(7)]})
df1
output:
    col1 col2 teams1
0   SF  NYG 8
1   SF  NYG 2
2   SF  NYG 9
3   SF  NYG 4
4   SF  NYG 8
5   SF  NYG 3
6   SF  NYG 1
```

I can see a solution for pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns). But this solution will collect all the data on the driver side which is not what I want to happen. I want a koalas (pandas on pyspark) solution

Comment: [this](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/transform_apply.html) might be helpful.

Comment: it's so much easier in pyspark - do you really want a koalas solution? pyspark - `new_sdf = kdf.to_spark().withColumn('col1', sdf.teams[0]).withColumn('col2', sdf.teams[1])`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am learning it the hard way that I cannot freewheel my pandas knowledge to pyspark just because I can now import pandas from pyspark. There are way too many gotchas in pandas on pyspark and pyspark API would be easier for all the use cases. Still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found to use only functions that operate on workers and do not collect all the data to the driver is

```
df['teams'] \
  .astype(str) \
  .str.replace('\[|\]', '') \
  .str.split(pat=',', n=1, expand=True)

#     0     1
# 0  SF   NYG
# 1  SF   NYG
# 2  SF   NYG
# 3  SF   NYG
# 4  SF   NYG
# 5  SF   NYG
# 6  SF   NYG
```

I had to transform the column as type *string* because it was a numpy array, and pyspark couldn't operate with it.

---

To get the initial dataframe along its other columns, you can use a simple `concat`:

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

ks.concat([
  df['teams'].astype(str).str.replace('\[|\]', '').str.split(pat=',', n=1, expand=True),
  df.drop(columns='teams')
], axis=1)

#     0     1  teams1
# 0  SF   NYG       2
# 1  SF   NYG       2
# 2  SF   NYG       1
# 3  SF   NYG       1
# 4  SF   NYG       7
# 5  SF   NYG       8
# 6  SF   NYG       6
```